# sed: ignore a substring that may or may not be present

Tags: regex, sed

With sed, I need to match and ignore a substring, that may or may not exist

Imagine I have these four strings, each on a separate line:

```
>package-1.22.3.src.tar.gz<
>package-1.22.4.src.tar.gz<
>package-1.23.tar.gz<
>package-1.23.1.tar.gz<
```

This is what I tried:

```
sed "s,.*>package-\(.[^<]*\)\(\.src\)\?\.tar.*<,\1,g"
```

I want a sed regex that will output this:

```
1.22.3
1.22.4
1.23
1.23.1
```

However, I get

```
1.22.3.src
1.22.4.src
1.23
1.23.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.[^<]*` pattern matches any char with `.` and then `[^<]*` matches any 0+ chars other than `<`. It matches `.src` part, hence the optional `\(\.src\)\?` does not need to match, and the `.src` lands in Group 1.

If you want to fix your current code, just match digits and dots after `package-` with `[0-9.]*`:

```
sed "s,.*>package-\([0-9.]*\)\(\.src\)\?\.tar.*<,\1,g"
                    ^^^^^^^
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YtfQlY)

If you have GNU `grep` you may also use a PCRE pattern like

```
grep -oP ">package-\K\d+(\.\d+)+"
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/w6fbFt). Here, after `>package-` is matched the text is removed from the match with `\K` operator and then 1+ digits followed with 1 or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits are matched and returned with the help of `-o` option.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, for the nice explanation.  Following your suggestion to match the digits and dots did work.  I knew that .[^<]* was rather greedy, but I thought that sed would see the following group (.src)? and not consume it as part of the .[^<]* match.  Obviously, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` should work:

`sed -E -n 's/.*-(.*\.[0-9]+).*<$/\1/p'`

Output:

```
1.22.3
1.22.4
1.23
1.23.1
```